# How do I keep Weblogic from using an ExpressionInterceptor?

Tags: java, jsp, weblogic, java-8, weblogic12c

I am working on migrating a website from Java 6, running on Weblogic 11g (10.3.5) to Java 8, running Weblogic 12c (12.1.3).  I have found several issues (it helps that others on my team have tried it before, without enough success), but one seems insurmountable, and I can't find out anything about it.

One of our JSPs fails to load in the browser with a `weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException`, complaining that "The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit."  Examining the differences between the generated `.java` file for the JSP in two versions of Weblogic, I see that each JSP expression is wrapped in an ExpressionInterceptor.

For example, in WebLogic 10 running Java 6, `<%=user.getLanguage()%>` becomes `out.print(user.getLanguage());`.  In WebLogic 12 running Java 8, it becomes:

```
out.print(_jsp_expressionInterceptor.intercept(
    String.valueOf(user.getLanguage()), pageContext,
    weblogic.servlet.jsp.ExpressionInterceptor.Type.Scripting));
```

It seems to me that the extra few method calls - 2 method calls, about 250 times in the file - is enough to bring the `_jspService` method above the 64K limit.  (The method size in Java 6, based on output from `javap`, is 62912 bytes, so that makes sense.)

My question is: is there any way to keep Weblogic from generating the calls to the `ExpressionInterceptor`?

Thanks.

Comment: Has anyone else even heard of `ExpressionInterceptor`?

Comment: May be it is a servlet runtime which comes with weblogic 12c. Try using different servlet runtime may be that will solve the problem. I tried to see the implementation of the WLS servlet runtime but it seems Oracle tries to keep a secret wind about it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue that has a patch for 12.1.3 & 12.1.2
Bug 17968606